# extern "C" does not enable C headers to use C++ reserved words

Tags: c++, c, reserved-words

I'm trying to build an Apple Open Source driver stack, the IOGraphicsFamily.

It `#includes` some xnu kernel headers.  These are all C, but the C++ code protects them with `extern "C"`.  However I am getting compile errors on all the C++ keywords such as `private` and `new`.

I looked up C keywords in google but didn't find `private` or `new` listed.  However the following code fails to compile:

```
bar.cpp:3:13: error: expected unqualified-id
typedef int new;
            ^
bar.cpp:6:2: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        new private;
        ^

extern "C" {

typedef int new;

typedef struct _bar {
    new private;
} bar;

}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    bar foo;

    return (int)&foo;
}
```

It would be intractable to revise all the C++ keywords in the xnu codebase.

Apple is able to build IOGraphicsFamily; this leads me to suspect I've done something else wrong but I do not yet have the required insight.

Comment: `extern "C"` simply specifies that functions within are with C linkage.

Comment: do you have an XY problem here, what are you actually trying to do? typedeffing to a c++ keyword seems like bad form...

Comment: You either have the intractable task of fixing that abuse of keywords, or the task of writing a C wrapper that hides the abuse and can be used in C++. You are out of luck either way I'm afraid.

Comment: new is a keyword in c++ that makes a heap allocated object and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: To be honest, you make it seem like special effort was taken to *prevent* the xnu codebase from being used in C++.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not change language or compiler. You're still writing C++ and compiling C++. It *simply* prevents name-mangling inside the block.

Comment: Just now I read in the kernel README that the kernel build installs some headers in $DSTROOT/user/include.  Hopefully those headers will work better.  I previous tried to build IOGraphics without building the kernel first.

Answer (score 4):

> `extern "C"` does not enable C headers to use C++ reserved words

Nobody said it would. `extern "C"` affects essentially how the compiler/linker performs the lookup and/or call of the relevant functions; the parsing rules are not affected.

The only way out I see is either some ugly ugly `#define` trick, such as #defining the relevant keywords to something else before the includes, and #undefining them immediately after (which may not work if such identifiers refer to external symbols), or to compile the part of your program that require these headers as plain C, and possibly using it to form a "bridge" with the rest of the C++ program.

Comment: Possibly something needs to be different in IOGraphicsFamily's configuration so that it doesn't #include the offending headers.

Answer (score 0):

If this must be done what you probably need to do is compile the code with a c compiler, change your typedef to a #define, so you don't export keywords then when you compile your cpp use the extern for the header.

somefile.h

```
#define new int;

typedef struct _bar {
    new private;
} bar;

#undef new
```

somefile.c can do things that reference new... which isn't a type but an lexically replaced int

somefile.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    include somefile.h
}
```